# designing a database for a city travel guide application which let users explore places and plan trip

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am currently working on a city travel guide application which let users explore places and plan trip.

In the account module, the following functions are to be considered:

1. User can register by providing primary email and password.
2. Registered users can add their personal details like they can add full name, secondary email, country and city.
3. User can setup their profile like they can add profile picture, Display name, places they have visited etc.
4. When they open own/ other's profile, their profile info (like photo and Display name) and statistics like their 'trip' count, 'likes' count, 'reviews' count are to be shown.

I have designed database tables for account module as follows:

```
 1. User_Account_details(user_id, primary_email, secondary_email, password)
 2. User_Personal_details(user_id, first_name, last_name, country, city)
 3. User_Profile(user_id, profile_picture, display_name)
 4. User_Statistics(user_id, trips_count, likes_count, reviews_count)
```

There are 3 more tables for cities and countries so that when user add country , then the app retrieve it from database and according cities are displayed in suggestions for city textbox.

```
 1. country(country_id, country_name)
 2. city(city_id, city_name)
 3. country_city_association(country_id, city_id)
```

Can anyone tell me if there is anything missing in my tables? or the tables are normalized or not? or if they are missing proper relations etc? I am newbie in database design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if the City table included the 'country_id'; this way you won't need the 'country_city_association' table. A city can only be in one country! Whilst it could be claimed that a valid entry in the 'city' table would be 'Boston', which would require at least two entries in the association table (Massachusetts and Lincolnshire), this isn't a very good idea.

The User_Personal_details is completely wrong. If you want to show all the places where a user has visited, then this table only needs user_id, city_id and a date. If the intention was to store where the user is normally located, then the city_id should be in the user_account_details table. First and last names should also be in the account details table.

The user_statistics table would prevent the database from achieving third normal form: all the data in this table can be retrieved by querying the other tables.

Comment: as you said: "The user_statistics table would prevent the database from achieving third normal form: all the data in this table can be retrieved by querying the other tables." ya, but would it not take more time? since, multiple table lookups have to be done?

Comment: @xyz: it will probably take less time to perform a query such as 'select user_id, count (*) from visits group by user_id' then it would to update your statistics table every time an event happens. You will also have experience problems keeping this table in sync. You should never (or at least, rarely) maintain summed columns in a table.